# Detecting accelerometer shakes android

Tags: android, accelerometer, shake

I'm trying to detect left, right, up and down shakes. I researched and found this code.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {

                float[] values = event.values;

                // Movement
                float x = values[0];
                float y = values[1];
                float z = values[2];


                long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if ((actualTime - lastUpdate) > 100) 
                {
                    long diffTime = (actualTime - lastUpdate);
                    lastUpdate = actualTime;


                    if(Round(x,4)>8.0000){
                        Log.d("sensor", "=====LEFT====");


                    }
                    else if(Round(x,4)<-8.0000){
                        Log.d("sensor", "=====RIGHT====");

                    }
                    else if(Round(z,4) < -0.0){
                       Log.d("sensor", "=====UP====");


                    }

                    else if(Round(y,4) < 1.0){
                        Log.d("sensor", "=====DOWN====");

                    }

                float speed = Math.abs(x+y+z - last_x - last_y - last_z) / diffTime * 10000;

                if (speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
                    //Log.d("sensor", "shake detected w/ speed: " + speed);
                    //Toast.makeText(this, "shake detected w/ speed: " + speed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                last_x = x;
                last_y = y;
                last_z = z;
                }
            }

        }
```

I tried to study it but I have some questions.
1. Where can I set the delay every after shake detection? I want it to detect a shake after 1 second of the last detected shake.
2. Why is that if I place it to a flat surface, it always detects down.
3. I can't detect a right movement shake

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First off, this code appears to detect movement rather than a shake (where I understand shake to be a motion which goes one way, then back the other), which might be causing problems in how you understand it's working.

> Where can I set the delay every after shake detection? I want it to detect a shake after 1 second of the last detected shake.

`if ((actualTime - lastUpdate) > 100)` is where the interval between detections occurs - the 100 here tells the program to only see what the change is after 100 ms, so if you wanted 1 second, change this to 1000

> Why is that if I place it to a flat surface, it always detects down.

I'm not entirely sure of the context and direction here as it's not clear, but don't forget that 'down' as you think of it might not be down in your space, but in the phone's, where down is only down when the phone is upright. If the phone is on it's back, left and right are the same, but down (i.e. towards the ground) is actually back for the sensor, as it's towards the back of the phone.

> 1. I can't detect a right movement shake

TBH I've no idea why, the code seems fine here. May be a phone thing, may be an implementation problem (as I said, the above code is movement overall, not a returning 'shake', so it could be how you're shaking it right to test this isn't triggering it, but your shake left is triggering it

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Well, this code is just right for my app. Can you suggest a solution to prevent the movement when placing it to a flat surface? The right movement gives me headache.